# Diffrence between using proxy in browser and in code

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, python-requests, http-proxy, urllib3

Currently im trying to understand a little bit more about networking. 
Recently i had occuring that a proxy, which is working on browser when requesting site X, didnt work in code when requesting site X with the code and not the browser.

The Request in code worked when i didnt use a proxy. When i added the proxy, which works in browser, requesting the site didnt work. (403)

So my conclusion is that browsers and code ( in my case python requests/urllib3) handle proxys diffrently. Otherwise there wouldnt be anyreason for site X to handle those request diffrently. (cause it worked in code when not using proxy)

Is there any source or smth i could read more about why this is occuring ?

Comment: If you showed us the code, we might be able to help.  Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: The code wont help in this case. It is simply setting a proxy with requests. Headers, ciphers and everytihng are set correctly. 

Its more of a theoretical questions. Diffrence between proxy handled by browser and handled by code.